# Unable to find aggregate in Hasura

Tags: sql, postgresql, graphql, hasura

On Hasura's GraphQl explore the unbale to find the aggregate option. Manually typing query also resulting in error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is other then admin account for others we have to enable the **Aggregation queries permissions**

For every table **`Table -> Permissions -> Click select option on that role -> Aggregation queries permissions -> Enable -> Save`**

[image: Hasura aggregate permission]

Now once you refresh your explorer you will get the aggregate listed in your query console for that table.